# WooCommerce: Display also product variation description on cart items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-variations

I'm trying to display my **product variation description** in my Cart. I have tried inserting this code in the **`cart.php`** template:

```
if ( $_product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {echo $_product->get_variation_description();}
```

By following this documentation https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

But it's still not showing up.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, thanks so much for the help. I just tried it today and it's not working for me. My programming knowledge is very limited so I apologize in advance for dumb mistakes. I inserted your code within my cart.php (see https://github.com/jessica16002002/Tega/blob/master/cart.php). Any chance you can take a look and help me find out what's wrong? Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Updated for WooCommerce version 3 and above

Since WooCommerce 3, [**`get_variation_description()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product.html#_get_variation_description) is now deprecated and replaced by [**`get_description()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_description) `WC_Product` method.

To get your **product item variation description** *(filtering variation product type condition)*, you can use the following hooked function instead:

```
// Cart page (and mini cart)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'cart_item_product_description', 20, 3);
function cart_item_product_description( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) {
        if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ) {
            $description = $cart_item['data']->get_description(); // variation description
        } else {
            $description = $cart_item['data']->get_short_description(); // product short description (for others)
        }

        if ( ! empty($description) ) {
            return $item_name . '<br><div class="description">
                <strong>' . __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: '. $description . '
            </div>';
        }
    }
    return $item_name;
}

// Checkout page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'cart_item_checkout_product_description', 20, 3);
function cart_item_checkout_product_description( $item_quantity, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ) {
        $description = $cart_item['data']->get_description(); // variation description
    } else {
        $description = $cart_item['data']->get_short_description(); // product short description (for others)
    }

    if ( ! empty($description) ) {
        return $item_quantity . '<br><div class="description">
            <strong>' . __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: '. $description . '
        </div>';
    }

    return $item_quantity;
}
```

Now the description is just displayed between the title and the variation attributes values *(if there is any)*.

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec . Thanks for this code (Case 1). Should this still work in latest WC (3.x)? I tried it, and it's just showing "Description: " with nothing else. I'd love to get this working.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks! Just to update, for Case 1, replace $item->get_variation_description(); with $item->get_description(); for (now) current versions of WooCommerce.

Comment: @jason Thanks again, I have enhanced and updated the code. Is now compatible also with WooCommerce version 3+.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for WC 3.0

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'cart_variation_description', 20, 3);
function cart_variation_description( $title, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $item = $cart_item['data'];

    if(!empty($item) && $item->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        return $item->get_name();
    } else
        return $title;
}
```

Comment: This works well but it loses the product link. Is there a way to still make it a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it via global variable `$woocommerce` also-

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart_data = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach ($cart_data as $value) {
    $_product = $value['data'];
    if( $_product->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
        echo $_product->id . '<br>';
    }
}
```

I already check it.

Comment: This is the old deprecated way… The new way since +/- 1 year is `WC()->cart` syntax without any need of `$global woocommerce;`… check the code on woocommerce templates or in core files, you will see.