# Add product description to cart items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I'm struggling to find a simple solution to this problem I'm having with One-page-checkout plugin for Woocommerce.

My client would like to add the product description next to the product title in cart items. 
Any thoughts on how I can manipulate the code to show the description?

This is what I have actually:

[image]

I would think that this plugin would just be hiding the description somewhere but I can't locate it anywhere in the code.

Comment: What version of WooCommerce are you using right now?

Comment: I am using Version 4.8.2

Comment: That is the latest Wordpress version but you are probably on WooCommerce version 3.2 if you have updated the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 ways to do it (making work for products and product variations):

1). With custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_get_item_data`** action hook ***(The best way)***:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'customizing_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function customizing_cart_item_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $description = $cart_item['data']->get_description(); // Get the product description

    // For product variations when description is empty
    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 && empty( $description ) ){
        // Get the parent variable product object
        $parent_product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );
        // Get the variable product description
        $description = $parent_product->get_description();
    }

    // If product or variation description exists we display it
    if( ! empty( $description ) ){
        $cart_data[] = array(
            'key'      => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'    => $description,
            'display'  => $description,
        );
    }
    return $cart_data;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

*… or …*

2). With custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_item_name`** filter hook:

[WooCommerce: Display also product variation description on cart items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045038/woocommerce-display-also-product-variation-description-on-cart-items/39045248#39045248)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code in your functions.php located in your root of your theme folder. Not sure if it still works as I'm not active in Wordpress development anymore. *[untested]*

**Updated: this should probably work for WooCommerce 3+**

**Using woocommerce_cart_item_name hook:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'cart_description', 20, 3);
function cart_description( $name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Get the corresponding WC_Product
    $product_item = $cart_item['data'];

    if(!empty($product_item)) {
        // WC 3+ compatibility
        $description = $product_item->get_description();
        $result = __( 'Description: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $description;
        return $name . '<br>' . $result;
    } else
        return $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: that didn't appear to work.. thanks for trying though!

Comment: I used echo $cart_item['data']->get_description(); and it worked.