# Enable Shortcode usage in WooCommerce WC_Product get_description() method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I am using the 2nd code snippet from *[Add product description to cart items in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732243/add-product-description-to-cart-items-in-woocommerce/46740724#46740724)* answer and added it to my function.php file to display the product description in the WooCommerce cart. It works great but within my product description is a shortcode from this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-divi-shortcode/ and it does not display in the cart correctly. The shortcode [showmodule id="261"] is displayed instead.

Comment: Is  [showmodule id="261"]  always in the same position in the description? Like at the begin or at the end?

Comment: Yes, it is always in the same position at the top. @LoicTheAztec code solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @StuartHingston Is better to comment in my answer comment zone if you want me to get notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need simply to embed the product descition in WordPress [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'customizing_cart_item_data', 10, 3);
function customizing_cart_item_data( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // The label
    $label = __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' );

    // Get the product description
    $description = $cart_item['data']->get_description();

    // For product variations when description is empty
    if( $cart_item['data']->is_type('variation') && empty( $description ) ){
        // Get the parent variable product object
        $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['data']->get_parent_id() );
        // Get the variable product description
        $description = $product->get_description();
    }

    if( ! empty( $description ) ){
        $item_name .= '<p class="item-description" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
            <strong>'.$label.'</strong>: <br>' . do_shortcode( $description ) . '
        </p>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and  works.

Comment: Thank you. This worked great. Is there a way to also hide the product title in the cart? I can not target it with CSS as it does not have a class so the description is also affected.

Comment: Ok, yes I did and was unable to get it to work. I will post a new question now. Thank you.

Comment: @StuartHingston Sorry, simply replace `$item_name .= '<p class="item-description"` by `$item_name = '<p class="item-description"` (removing the `.` before `=`), this way the product name will not be displayed.